# Pandas - mean of a data frame only returns the mean of the first column

Tags: python, pandas

here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("aps.csv")
df.replace('na', np.NaN, inplace=True)
print (df.mean(axis=0))
```

I expect the mean of each column, but it returns only the mean of the first column! why?

```
aa_000    59336.499567
dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you outout df,dtypes

Comment: @Wen, yes, good idea, except the first one, the rest is "object". aa_000     int64
ab_000    object
ac_000    object
ad_000    object
ae_000    object
af_000    object
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that other columns are `dtype` `object`

Try:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mean()
```

Comment: do you know why the dtype turns out to be object?!

Answer (score 3):

You can try `na_values`

```
pd.read_csv(r"test.csv",na_values ='na')
```

Comment: do you know why the dtype turns out to be object?!